# Issue to automize download of data with cds api

Tags: python, automation, python-requests, cds, cds.copernicus

I'm trying to download data from CMIP6 climate projections ( https://cds.climate.copernicus.eu/cdsapp#!/dataset/projections-cmip6?tab=form ) with the cds.api extension on python.

The problem is that I don't get how to automatize the code in order to download successively the data from different existing models with a loop.

```
import __main__
import cdsapi
import sys
#import cdstoolbox 
import numpy as np


c = cdsapi.Client()

model=['cnrm_cm6_1','cmcc_cm2_sr5']
  
    
for k in range(len(model)):
        c.retrieve(
            'projections-cmip6',
            {
                'format': 'zip',
                'experiment': 'historical',
                'temporal_resolution': 'monthly',
                'variable': 'precipitation',
                'model': model[k],
                'year': '2010',
                'month': '01',
                'area': [
                    -2, 29, -3,
                    30,
                    ],
                },
                'download.zip')
```

The process takes place if I put only the name of a model outside the loop, instead of model[k]. But if I try to automate this query with a list, I am unable to get results.

Here is what I get in the Console:

```
2023-01-17 09:11:17,601 INFO Sending request 
to https://download-0000.copernicus-climate.eu/api/v2/resources/projections-cmip6
2023-01-17 09:11:17,607 WARNING Recovering from connection error [HTTPSConnectionPool
(host='download-0000.copernicus-climate.eu', port=443): 
Max retries exceeded with url: /api/v2/resources/projections-cmip6 
(Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection 
object at 0x00000222E751B3D0>: Failed to establish 
a new connection: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed'))],
 attemps 0 of 500
2023-01-17 09:11:17,608 WARNING Retrying in 120 seconds
```

Comment: Apart from SSL warnings, this runs to normal completion on my system

Comment: @Pingu And you use exactly the same code, with a list?

Comment: The fact that you're using a list is irrelevant. The problem stems from download-0000.copernicus-climate.eu which doesn't exist

Comment: I read in others topics that it's supposed to work with server 0000, but here it seems it's not the case, do you know how to specify another server (0001,0002,...)?

Comment: You need to be in touch with the author(s) of the cdsapi module. This is not a Python issue *per se*

Comment: @Pingu It seems it's under maintenance. By the past, it worked, and the request was sent. But with a list, the request was sent but did not finish, and the elements were therefore not downloadable on the copernicus site, but with only one element yes. Are you able to download the data on the site by using a loop with several models?

Answer (score 0):

Revised code that works with a list of models:

```
import cdsapi
import urllib3

urllib3.disable_warnings()

c = cdsapi.Client()

models = ['cnrm_cm6_1', 'cmcc_cm2_sr5']
params = {
    'format': 'zip',
    'experiment': 'historical',
    'temporal_resolution': 'monthly',
    'variable': 'precipitation',
    'year': '2010',
    'month': '01',
    'area': [-2, 29, -3, 30]
}


for model in models:
    params['model'] = model
    c.retrieve('projections-cmip6', params, f'{model}.zip')
```